# Merging a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, join, dataframe, finance

I have a large data frame with financial data that looks like this :

```
id      Tradedate    name          hour open    close
19897   2013-01-30   instrument1   1   18.01   13.50
19898   2013-01-30   instrument2   2   15.72    8.99
19899   2013-01-30   instrument3   3   12.80   11.42
19900   2013-01-30   instrument4   4   12.71   12.85
```

There are a couple thousand instruments in the above data frame. I have another "to be traded" data frame of a dozen or so instruments  that looks like this:

```
id    name   hour 
1 instrument3 17     
2 instrument4 24    
3 instrument5 15    
4 instrument6 19
```

The issue I'm running into is that I cannot get `subset` to return a data frame which contains only the instrument-hour combinations in the "to be traded" vector. I have tried this:`subset(financial_data, subset= paste(name, hour) %in% paste(to_be_traded$name, portfolio$hour))`, but it returns the full financial data frame. I know that this could be accomplished in sql with something like an `INNER JOIN`, but I do not know how to do this in R. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INNER JOINs in R are accomplished with `merge`. There is no overlap in the unique combinations of your data matching those two columns, but if there were, they would be delivered with:

```
merge(dat1, dat2, by=c("name", "hour"))
```

If you want OUTER JOINs (left or right) they can be delivered by specifying all.x or all.y in the `merge` call.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `merge(financial_data, trade_data)` gets the job done in this case.

Comment: I don't think so. The 'id' column will be matched across the dataframe names and that was not part of the specification.

Comment: Good point. I didn't see the 'id' variable. You must specify the columns then.